# What should go inside the brackets of the "constructor" function in ionic?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I know that in the `constructor` I load some dependencies as plugins or load providers that I will use in the class. but I do not know what should go inside the brackets? in some cases it is empty, but in others, variables are defined. What is the best practice and when it is agreed within these brackets, what should be included?

```
constructor(
 public navCtrl: NavController // for example
){
 ????
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in general constructor is used during class instantiation and it is considered to be a good spot to initialize values of properties of the class. You can search SO for similar questions (difference between constructor and lifecycle hooks etc).

the way I adopted it was:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<div></div>`
})
export class SomeComponentWithForm {

  // here you declare and type class properties/variables:
  var: type

  constructor(
      // here you do dependency injection:
  ){
    // here you initialize class' properties values:
    this.var = value
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
      // here your perform activities on first load of the component
  }

  other lifecycle hooks

}
```